# Is it equivalent oracle cursor parameter feature in mysql?

Tags: mysql, cursor

Is it equivalent ORACLE cursor parameter feature in MySQL ?

For example :-

```
CURSOR cursorname(paramter_name datatype) IS SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
CURSOR select_curs IS SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = @id;

set @id = 1;
OPEN  ..
FETCH ..
CLOSE ..
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

The procedure uses the var_id_res parameter to specify a particular reservation:

This procedure parameter is used to control a cursor to select only items that correspond

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `UpdatePriceAndVatAndDiscountForReservationItems`(
        IN var_id_res INTEGER
    )
...to the reservation passed by the parameter:

-- the line reserve curosr


 DECLARE cur_res CURSOR FOR
        SELECT  id_line
        ,       id_prod
        ,       disc_bool
        ,       no_days
        FROM    line_reserve 
        WHERE   id_res = var_id_res;
```

Comment: I have to pass more than one value in parameter dynamically.